# easyXDM compability with IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain, messaging

I used easyXDM for socket messaging in my project.
I have a page and two diffrent iframe can be opened in this page using easyXDM socket messaging. Only one of this iframe has both side communication with main page.

---

```
var remoteProvider1 = "https://localhost/provider/first";
var remoteProvider2 = "https://localhost/provider/second";
...
var socket1 = function() {
    ...
    socketA = new easyXDM.Socket({
remote : remoteProvider1 ,
container : container,
    props : {
        },
        onMessage : function(message, origin) {
            onMessageEvent(message, origin);
        },
        onReady : function() {
            socketBar.postMessage("hi");
        }
    });
};

var socket2 = function() {
    ...
    socketB = new easyXDM.Socket({
    remote : remoteProvider2 ,
        container : container,
        props : {
        }
    });
};
```

---

As you can see in code, socket1 communicates with remote provider1 by sending an recieving message and on remote provider side easyxdm configured as well.
socket2 only open an iframe. It dose not need to communicate with remote provider2. so no easyXDM cofigured on remote provider side.

It works fine in IE9. In IE8 the first iframe opens and works fine. but the second one open an iframe with no nontent ... only a white page.

Just want to know if anybody have experienced the same thing or have any idea about the reason.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/04/05/cross-domain-quirks-in-ie8/ may be a potential candidate.